# Return an entire recordset x times (where x is the number of rows in another table)

Tags: sql, database, oracle

Let's say I have 2 tables.

TableA only has one column and looks like this (it will always only have one column but the values in this column will change over time):

```
TableA
------
Column1:
   A
   G
   T
   R
```

Table B has many columns (but none of these columns will ever match a value from column1 of Table A). ie

```
TableB
------
Column1:     Column2:      Column3:    
   65           xyz          fgdsg
   97           tmkl          sjg
   184          soi           trhd
```

I would like to be able to return the below result set in a query:

```
 TabA.Column1:   TabB.Column1:   TabB.Column2:      TabB.Column3:
 -------------   ------------     ------------        ----------    
       A              65           xyz                  fgdsg
       A              97           tmkl                  sjg
       A              184          soi                   trhd
       G              65           xyz                  fgdsg
       G              97           tmkl                  sjg
       G              184          soi                   trhd
       T              65           xyz                  fgdsg
       T              97           tmkl                  sjg
       T              184          soi                   trhd
       R              65           xyz                  fgdsg
       R              97           tmkl                  sjg
       R              184          soi                   trhd
```

To accomplish this I thought of unioning TableB x times where x is the count from TableA but I don't think you can create x number of unions dynamically in SQL alone. I am only looking for a solution in SQL code (it may incorporate the use of pre-defined PL/SQL functions).

Comment: Just a "cross join" doesn't work? (No where clause is required).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just a [CROSS JOIN](http://www.sqlguides.com/sql_cross_join.php) doesn't work? A cross join results in the [Cartesian product](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_product) of the input sets.

```
SELECT * FROM TableA CROSS JOIN TableB
```

Happy coding

Answer (score 1):

What you want is a cross join. Joining everything from table A to Table B.

```
SELECT * FROM TableA  
CROSS JOIN TableB
```